# build a cordova plugin for android from source code

Tags: eclipse, cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I'm a .Net developer and I've some basic information about java development , I'm developing a `multi-device-hybrid-apps` using visual studio and `cordova`.

I use a native plugin for push notifications [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) , I want to do some changes in this plugin using java , i downloaded `eclipse` and `ADT plugin` .

actually my problem is in using eclipse not in understanding java code (what is project template in eclipse should i use to create android library ), I've created a new android project and added the `PushPlugin` code that I downloaded from `GitHub` , but "android project" is generating an android app not just a `jar` file to use as a cordova plugin.

**What I want is**  to make some modifications in the plugin code and re-build it using eclipse to generate a new jar file.

please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i found a way to overcome this issue , It's mainly caused by my lack understanding to how cordova plugins works , so i decided to write steps , it may help someone who has few knowledge about java and cordova plugins.

to edit a downloaded (with source-code) plugin from github

- you don't need to install `eclipse` at all.
- you need to have some knowledge in `java` and android API
- in `visual studio` navigate to your plugin source code under `plugins` folder , in this case it's `\plugins\com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin\src\android\com\plugin\gcm`
- find the plugin starting class which will be a class `extends CordovaPlugin`
- edit what you want in java code
- now in order to re-build java code , you MUST **Clean** cordova project before making a new deploy.

That's all.

Comment: Can I edit main app code to extend cordova app without developing a plugin? As an example, how can I show alert by editing java code of cordova? (without js or plugin). Thanks